# WIA: setting dinamic page size

Tags: c#, .net, wia, page-size

I'm developing a WPF application to scan different documents with a scanner. The size of the documents won't be the same, can be variable.

I have my code working without scanner dialogs, and I would like the user not to have to preview the image and then scanning it to get the real size (resulting in two scans).

The problem is that I try to set page-size to auto before scanning

```
SetWIAProperty(item.Properties, "3097", 100);
```

but I get HRESULT: 0x80210067   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException.
I've googled to this and seens that my scanner is not supporting this property.

So, is there any way of achieving this? I need the resulting scanned image to be only the document, not all the scanner area (which I'm obtaning right now).
In case I couldn't tell the scanner to scan only the document, I've thought also in cropping the resulting image to obtain only the document I need, but don't know how to do this right now.

Here is my code:

```
                DeviceManager deviceManager = new DeviceManager();
                Device scanner = null;
                foreach (DeviceInfo deviceInfo in deviceManager.DeviceInfos)
                {
                    if (deviceInfo.DeviceID == scannerId)
                    {
                        scanner = deviceInfo.Connect();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (scanner == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Scanner not found");
                }

                Item item = scanner.Items[1] as Item;
                int dpi = 300;
                SetWIAProperty(item.Properties, "6146", 1); // 1 Color
                SetWIAProperty(item.Properties, "6147", dpi); // dpis 
                SetWIAProperty(item.Properties, "6148", dpi); // dpis 
                // This line throws the exception  
                //SetWIAProperty(item.Properties, "3097", 100); // page size 0=A4, 1=letter, 2=custom, 100=auto

                try
                {
                    ICommonDialog wiaCommonDialog = new CommonDialog(); 
                    ImageFile scannedImage = (ImageFile)wiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer(item, FormatID.wiaFormatPNG, false);

                    if (scannedImage != null)
                    {
                        ImageProcess imgProcess = new ImageProcess();
                        object convertFilter = "Convert";
                        string convertFilterID = imgProcess.FilterInfos.get_Item(ref convertFilter).FilterID;
                        imgProcess.Filters.Add(convertFilterID, 0);
                        SetWIAProperty(imgProcess.Filters[imgProcess.Filters.Count].Properties, "FormatID", FormatID.wiaFormatPNG);
                        scannedImage = imgProcess.Apply(scannedImage);
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"D:\temp\scanwia3.png"))
                            System.IO.File.Delete(@"D:\temp\scanwia3.png");
                        scannedImage.SaveFile(@"D:\temp\scanwia3.png");
                    }
                    scannedImage = null;
                }
                finally
                {
                    item = null;
                    scanner = null;
                }
```

And SetWIAProperty function:

```
private static void SetWIAProperty(IProperties properties, object propName, object propValue)
    {
        Property prop = properties.get_Item(ref propName);
        prop.set_Value(ref propValue);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards,

Jose.

Answer (score 0):

Property `Page Size` belongs to device, not to item.

```
var WIA_IPS_PAGE_SIZE = "3097";
var WIA_PAGE_AUTO = 100;

SetWIAProperty(scanner.Properties, WIA_IPS_PAGE_SIZE, WIA_PAGE_AUTO);
```

Comment: I've tried with this, but I've got the same exception. I finally gave up with this and the final approach is showing a preview dialog for scanning: the users first preview and crop the image, and then scan the final image. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm scanning using NTwain, and it has auto size enabled by default.

Comment: Maybe NTwain provides some capabilities I can't achieve directly with WIA. But unfortunately I can't change to NTwain right now.